# Laravel, select from DB from the end, but in asc order

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get rows from the end of the table, but in `asc` order.

We have this data: Result: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 99.
`Message::select()->where('thread_id', $id)->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')->get();`

If we change `orderBy` to `desc` and use it with `take(5)`, then we have: Result: 99, 98, 97, 96, 95.
`Message::select()->where('thread_id', $id)->skip(0)->take(5)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();`

How can I get Result: 95, 96, 97, 98, 99?

p.s. of course I can do it with `skip(95)->take(5)->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')`, but how to do it dynamically.

Comment: Did you try `->get()->reverse()`?

Comment: Looks like 'reverse()' does not change the result of this query...

Comment: @Alex `reverse()` operates on the collection that is returned by the querybuilder. So while it doesn't change the query, it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by this way:

```
$messages_query = Message::select()->where('thread_id', 1)->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc');
$count = $messages_query->count();
$messages = $messages_query->skip($count-$count_to_take)->take($count_to_take)->get();
```

Where `$count_to_take` for example `=10`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the `reverse()` method to the collection, such as:

```
$messages = Message::select()->where('thread_id', $id)->skip(0)->take(5)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();

$messages = $messages->reverse();
```

You can also opt for:

```
$messages = $messages->sortBy('updated_at');
```

Comment: `$messages = $messages->sortBy('updated_at');` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Message::select()->where('thread_id', $id)->skip(0)->take(5)
->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get()->reverse();
```

Comment: It wont change the query, it will reverse the collection and get you your desired outcome

Comment: Ideally, you dont want to change the query because the query selects the 5 items that you need. You just want to reverse the collection order and my answer does exactly that